# File not exist when run mysql database migrations on windows

Tags: mysql, docker, go, database-migration, golang-migrate

I cloned an existing repository (repository created by a team in my office which deals with subscriptions in a certain app we are working on) which have some database migration files inside the path ..\internal\db\migrations , this is migration files path.
First of all i run the command `docker compose up` .for an existing docker.yaml , then i run the command `go build` then `go run .` .

I made a debug and the app reaches the point when it is about to run the migration file then it displays an error:

> Failed to initialize App. Error: first D:\subscription-store: file does not exist

although I checked the paths through debugging and they are correct and at the same time the migration files all are exists.

I am using visual studio code as an editor, Go version 1.15 ,docker and MySQL. I am running on enviroment windows 10.

Comment: more info would be be helpful. You say " I cloned an existing repository",  which repository? , You say "I made a search and had found that this is a common issue when running docker on windows", but you do no supply the links where you did find this info...

Comment: I updated the question and posted the answer , i resolved it today

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging and searching , it was found that the repository uses some paths to get the migration files from the local drive . the paths was written for Mac in the code base and i cloned the repository on a windows machine so it didn't work .

The error specifically happened in the call of the function

```
migrate.NewWithDatabaseInstance(
        fmt.Sprintf("file://%s", fullPath),
        "mysql",
        driver,
    )
```

The generated path for the first parameter was

```
file//d:\\subscription-store\\....\\db\\migrations
```

And this is wrong for windows as the driver d: shouldn't be supported in the path .
it is resolved as following

```
"file:///"+"subscription-store\\....\\db\\migrations"
```

When the above URL sent to the function rather than the old one , it worked successfully.